# iframe not working in Magento development environment, but works in live

Tags: magento, iframe, cross-domain, magento-1.7

I am working on a Magento application which uses iframe on the product details page.But when I moved the application to the development environment the iframe stopped working.

```
<iframe width="980px" height="950px" frameborder="0" src="http://www.example.com/somedirectory/index.php?action=main&amp;case=v2&amp;type=std&amp;model=xyz" style="border:none;" id="my_iframe">
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body></body>
</html>
</iframe>
```

There is content under head and the body part of iframe when in Live environment.

The iframe code is in the view.phtml file.

**Update** : when I statically replace the my development site url "http://www.example.com" with live site url in the iframe things start working? But how to fix for the development environment.

Please suggest some solution for this.

Comment: may be cross domain origin issue. it might be working in live site because the domains are same. I mean the iframe has the same domain name as the live site. can't say.. please explain more.

Comment: @Mr_Green I have changed the url in the demo site iframe as per demo site url, still it is not working.

Comment: @Mr_Green Can this be blocked from cPanel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were some unclosed php tags in the php file which was being used by the iframe.
When I closed the php tags properly,it started working.